# How to print substring in React JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have two variables in my react component. I want to divide one variable from another and print the value for only one decimal place. So, I choose the substring method as following:

```
 <div className="col-md-8">
      {(total_star / total_user).substring(0,2)}
 </div>
```

In the output I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: (total_star / total_user).substring is not a function
```

Kindly help to print substring in jsx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the result is a `float` not a `string`, you could use `.toFixed(...)` instead of `substring`

```
(total_star / total_user).toFixed(2);
```

Or convert the result to `string` and the use `.substring(...)`

```
(total_star / total_user).toString().substring(0,2)
```

The first example may not get you the result you're looking for because `.substring(0, 2)` will give you the first two characters and `.toFixed(2)` will give you the result with two decimals after the decimal point.